# IME and catching (touch) events

Tags: android, logging, touch-event, ime

Im currently trying to get my diploma in psychology and i want to write about different types of keyboards for smartphones. To research this area i need a tool that measures times. As Im new to Android programming, my friend is helping me, but we got stuck. 
Here is what we need, and what we tried. Id really appreciate any help =)

**We need** a way to call a function before user input in IME begins and after user input in IME ends. (We need this only for timelogging, we dont need the actual input.)
We also need to call a function before user input for chosing autocorrection starts/ends.

We need to do this for all kinds of IMEs especially keyboards
like Swype, Swiftkey etc (though one of them working is enough)

**We tried:**

TextWatcher via addTextChangedListener
     - seems to be unreliable to get the times beforeTextChanged/afterTextChanged is randomly called, even within a gesture
       or multiple times within a gesture

subclassing EditText implementing OnTouchListener,
using onTouch()
- didnt seem to get called at all when using swype, so either we did it wrong or ime/swpye consumes those events,
   also tried it with onKeyPreIme, wasnt called either

**Ideal would be:**
a way of catching the "touch" events before they are passed to the IME to log the current time via System.currentTimeMillis()
the same "after" the gesture ends i.e. when the finger is released from display

**we dont need actual code, a link to the right command/documentation/widget would be sweet.**

You get bonus cookies if you are ever in berlin and need a place to ... get cookies :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is much of an answer, but...

Is your plan to write this in an Android application that you can distribute and run on anybody's device?

Sounds like whatever you do on the EditText or your application may not be enough because the IME is a separate module in Android, so you would not be able to get any information about auto correct or prediction or things like that (different IME have different of such features). You would only be able to get the text entered (or removed) from the text entry.

The best I can think of is for you to develop your own IME, then you can log anything you like in there.

To go about that, I would suggest, you first checkout this article from Android Developer:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

And then you can check out the source code for the default Latin IME there:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME.java

Although this one has probably much more than you need and has (I think) some links into the Android framework itself, so you cannot really build it as a separate module the way it is now.

Hope that helps